# UICollectionview and/or UITableview cells not selectable until after view scrolled?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uicollectionviewcell

For every collectionview and tableview within my app, none of them are recognising the selection of a cell unit AFTER the table or collection has been scrolled a little?

This only happens within this current app, no different methods have been used, no collection/table subclassing etc. All collection views and table views are implemented with all relevant dataSource and Delegates hooked up and implemented etc.

As this is a common thing will all my tables, I'm wondering if it is a setting within the project that is causing this.

If anyone has experienced and previously solved this issue, I'd appreciate any help.

Salient points that may be relevant -

-All collecitonviews / tableviews are set up on storyboard.

-All cells are added directly to table/collection within storyboard and cell view configured using their own class files.

-Deployment target 7.0 for iPhone only

-All tables/collection cells are loading fine, everything *looks* fine with no crashes... just that the tables need 'woken up' so to speak?

Thanks in advance,
Jim

Comment: Can you print the value of the property "cell.userInteractionEnabled" just before you returning it at cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Hi Gal, it returns YES in the console. Running NSLog it returns = 1 for the 5 visible cells

Comment: Managed to fix the issue, I was actioning a success block without dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue().for the data feeding to the tables... Phew!

Comment: Good job! might be helpful for others. Put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issue, and I fixed it by subclassing UICollectionViewCell/UITableViewCell and setting `selected` property to `NO` in `prepareForReuse` method.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    self.selected = NO;
}
```